# Add column by previous columns values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, multiplication

Here is table:

```
6   30  98  298 588 1598
36  2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
50  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Here is my dirty way to add new 'total' column:

```
df_cz['total'] = df_cz[6] *6 + df_cz[30] *30 + df_cz[98] *98 + ...
```

Is there a better way to calculate 'total' values base on  table head value and each row values.

Comment: Are those column names (6, 30, 98 etc.)?

Comment: Anyways if `NaN` is present then total will obviously be `NaN`.

Comment: @shivsn , i use `fillna` before add new column(not mentioned on question above)

Comment: @ayhan , yes, the type of header is integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with columns names converted [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (df_cz)
    6   30  98  298  588  1598
0  36  2.0 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  50  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN

df_cz['total'] = df_cz.mul(df_cz.columns.to_series()).sum(axis=1)
print (df_cz)
    6   30  98  298  588  1598  total
0  36  2.0 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  276.0
1  50  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  330.0
```